# Heatmap of common zip codes on state districts

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap, choropleth

I have a file of zip codes and their frequencies like so

```
ZIPs    Count
10065   10
10021   106
10003   5
```

I am trying to plot a density of these histograms based on their location on top of my state's Zip Code Tabulated Areas (ZCTAs).

I am trying to model myself after this: https://arilamstein.com/creating-zip-code-choropleths-choroplethrzip/. But my goal is different in that the 'fill' of the map would be counts based on the zip code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand how your goal is different.

Comment: Can you add code that generates your data ?